# Segue "Dead Zones" on custom tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So if I have  tableview with buttons on it, but also linking to a segue when you click the cell, how do I make it easier for users to hit the buttons without triggering a segue. I was thinking about putting a UIView under the buttons and make it so it wouldn't segue when people tried to push the buttons. However this isn't working and I can't think of anything.

Comment: create a `custom tableview cell` and , implement the `button action` inside the `custom table view cell class`.

Comment: "However this isn't working" because you forgot to make the view's user interaction enabled?

Comment: button on tableview or on cell?

Comment: Strikes me as a bad idea to have a button in a cell that also has a segue.